# utf8_bin or utf8_unicode for my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, utf

I'm going to create a new blog based on wordpress. Regarding the database, should I choose utf8_bin or utf8_unicode? I've read the differences between the two, but things are still not that clear to me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter much if you are just creating a wordpress blog.

But, according to me, you should go with the utf8_unicode.